# Why is this jQuery blur event / integer math failing?

Tags: jquery, int, onblur

I've got this jQuery to sum all values in "Amount" columns on exiting any of them, updating the "Total" text input with the total:

```
/* boxAmount1...boxAmount5 - when any of them change, update boxGrandTotal */
$(document).on("blur", '[id^="boxAmount"]', function (e) {
    var amount1 = $('[id$=boxAmount1]').val();
    var amount2 = $('[id$=boxAmount2]').val();
    var amount3 = $('[id$=boxAmount3]').val();
    var amount4 = $('[id$=boxAmount4]').val();
    var amount5 = $('[id$=boxAmount5]').val();
    var grandtotal = amount1 + amount2 + amount3 + amount4 + amount5;
    $('[id$=boxGrandTotal]').val(grandtotal);
});
```

However, it doesn't work, as you can see:

[image]

What have I overlooked?

### UPDATE

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/8tjangnu/) showing that even when using parseInt(), the code doesn't work Using jQuery 1.11.0, as I get "NaN" in the grand total box.

Comment: wait, looking more closely at your question, I think the problem is for another reason. Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle? Or show some HTML?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work any better even with the parseInt() jazz, so I'll fiddle around a bit and report back.

Comment: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/8tjangnu/
Using jQuery 1.11.0, I get "NaN" in the grand total box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parseInt` since `val()` returns a string

```
/* boxAmount1...boxAmount5 - when any of them change, update boxGrandTotal */
$(document).on("blur", '[id^="boxAmount"]', function (e) {
    var amount1 = parseInt($('[id$=boxAmount1]').val());
    var amount2 = parseInt($('[id$=boxAmount2]').val());
    var amount3 = parseInt($('[id$=boxAmount3]').val());
    var amount4 = parseInt($('[id$=boxAmount4]').val());
    var amount5 = parseInt($('[id$=boxAmount5]').val());
    var grandtotal = amount1 + amount2 + amount3 + amount4 + amount5;
    $('[id$=boxGrandTotal]').val(grandtotal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With help from three cats (AmmarCSE on this page (above), Bhavin Solanki [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462442/why-is-my-blur-event-handler-not-firing), and Sµßhrånil∂ [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/why-is-this-jquery-integer-math-failing#14737000006345941), I assembled the mashup for the working code:

```
$(document).on("blur", '.dplatypus-webform-field-input', function (e) {
    var amount1 = $('[id$=boxAmount1]').val() != '' ? parseInt($('[id$=boxAmount1]').val()) : 0;
    var amount2 = $('[id$=boxAmount2]').val() != '' ? parseInt($('[id$=boxAmount2]').val()) : 0;
    var amount3 = $('[id$=boxAmount3]').val() != '' ? parseInt($('[id$=boxAmount3]').val()) : 0;
    var amount4 = $('[id$=boxAmount4]').val() != '' ? parseInt($('[id$=boxAmount4]').val()) : 0;
    var amount5 = $('[id$=boxAmount5]').val() != '' ? parseInt($('[id$=boxAmount5]').val()) : 0;
    var grandtotal = amount1 + amount2 + amount3 + amount4 + amount5;
    $('[id$=boxGrandTotal]').val(grandtotal);
});
```

Thanks to the 3 jQueryeteers!

### UPDATE

I modified this slightly, realizing that there a gazillion elements on the page with the class "dplatypus-webform-field-input" assigned to them, most of which would just cause this event to fire to no avail/redundantly. So I added a second class to just the "amount" boxes like so (C#):

```
CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-input amountbox",
```

...and changed the jQuery to:

```
$(document).on("blur", '.amountbox', function (e) {
```

I give myself an amber star for that, and now consider there to be 4 jQueryeteers involved in this answer.

### UPDATE 2

I have changed it to float, and to display the total with 2 decimals:

```
$(document).on("blur", '.amountbox', function (e) {
    var amount1 = $('[id$=boxAmount1]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount1]').val()) : 0;
    var amount2 = $('[id$=boxAmount2]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount2]').val()) : 0;
    var amount3 = $('[id$=boxAmount3]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount3]').val()) : 0;
    var amount4 = $('[id$=boxAmount4]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount4]').val()) : 0;
    var amount5 = $('[id$=boxAmount5]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount5]').val()) : 0;
    var grandtotal = amount1 + amount2 + amount3 + amount4 + amount5;
    $('[id$=boxGrandTotal]').val(parseFloat(grandtotal).toFixed(2));
});
```

### UPDATE 3

And now force all entries to two digits:

```
$(document).on("blur", '.amountbox', function (e) {
    $('[id$=boxAmount1]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount1]').val()).toFixed(2));
    $('[id$=boxAmount2]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount2]').val()).toFixed(2));
    $('[id$=boxAmount3]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount3]').val()).toFixed(2));
    $('[id$=boxAmount4]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount4]').val()).toFixed(2));
    $('[id$=boxAmount5]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount5]').val()).toFixed(2));
    var amount1 = $('[id$=boxAmount1]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount1]').val()) : 0;
    var amount2 = $('[id$=boxAmount2]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount2]').val()) : 0;
    var amount3 = $('[id$=boxAmount3]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount3]').val()) : 0;
    var amount4 = $('[id$=boxAmount4]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount4]').val()) : 0;
    var amount5 = $('[id$=boxAmount5]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount5]').val()) : 0;
    var grandtotal = amount1 + amount2 + amount3 + amount4 + amount5;
    $('[id$=boxGrandTotal]').val(parseFloat(grandtotal).toFixed(2));
});
```

### UPDATE 4

Actually, Update 3 doesn't quite work, after all, as exiting/"blurring out of" one text input causes "NaN" to show up uninvited in all the blank ones (and the "grand total" text input). So, here's the tedious way to do it:

```
/* boxAmount1...boxAmount5 - when any of them change, update boxGrandTotal */
$(document).on("blur", '.amountbox', function (e) {
    var amount1 = $('[id$=boxAmount1]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount1]').val()) : 0;
    var amount2 = $('[id$=boxAmount2]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount2]').val()) : 0;
    var amount3 = $('[id$=boxAmount3]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount3]').val()) : 0;
    var amount4 = $('[id$=boxAmount4]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount4]').val()) : 0;
    var amount5 = $('[id$=boxAmount5]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount5]').val()) : 0;
    var grandtotal = amount1 + amount2 + amount3 + amount4 + amount5;
    $('[id$=boxGrandTotal]').val(parseFloat(grandtotal).toFixed(2));
});

$(document).on("blur", '[id$=boxAmount1]', function (e) {
    $('[id$=boxAmount1]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount1]').val()).toFixed(2));
});

$(document).on("blur", '[id$=boxAmount2]', function (e) {
    $('[id$=boxAmount2]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount2]').val()).toFixed(2));
});

$(document).on("blur", '[id$=boxAmount3]', function (e) {
    $('[id$=boxAmount3]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount3]').val()).toFixed(2));
});

$(document).on("blur", '[id$=boxAmount4]', function (e) {
    $('[id$=boxAmount4]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount4]').val()).toFixed(2));
});

$(document).on("blur", '[id$=boxAmount5]', function (e) {
    $('[id$=boxAmount5]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount5]').val()).toFixed(2));
});
```

...but I feel a plugin coming on; MaskMoney, perhaps?